# Angular: Encapsulation cause a CSS collision

Tags: css, angular, collision, encapsulation

I have a problem with some components. I have 2 different components, both with **encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None** activated. They have in common the class **parent**. I don't know why, but with encapsulation they share the class between them.

To be more specific:

comp1 have a container with class **parent**

comp2 have a container with class **parent**

Without encapsulation, the css is isolated, what is good! But when I add encapsulation the comp1 will have 2 styles, one from itself and one from **comp2**.

How I could fix this collision between styles?

Comment: If any dev's ans is correct then please do practice to up vote and accept the answer. so when any other dev has same problem so he/she can directly go to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`.